# ActiveMQ message group expiration

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

We are using message groups in ActiveMQ.

We will have about 100,000 message groups a day with 1 to 10 messages per group. A random (between 1 and 10) number of messages for the group will arrive at unknown times over about a 24 hour period.

Since we don't know how many messages will arrive for a particular message group, we cannot explicitly close the group. We do not want message groups to live forever though, since we suspect it would be a memory leak.

How can we achieve something similar to the below? Is there alternative we are missing?

messageGroup.setTimeToLive(48 hours)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about closing message groups; as a message group isn't managed individually per distinct value of `JMSXGroupID`. ActiveMQ creates hash code buckets per message group value (i.e. per value of the `JMSXGroupID` value is hashed and divided into buckets. So the hash code is calculated for the String value of `JMSXGroupID` then that value is put into a 'hash bucket' so that there is not a huge number of possible values to avoid memory exhaustion.

So the JMSXGroupID value can be a totally random string and the broker won't run out of RAM. We should update the [Message Groups documentatio](http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html)n to make this more clear though!

Comment: Thanks James! Lets say we create a `NMSXGroupID` of AA1234597 on Dec 15, 2015. Will ActiveMQ remember a month later the consumer that was assigned to AA1234597? (Assuming the message group was never explicitly closed and the consumer is still running)?

Comment: Yes; provided the broker and consumer keep running, the same consumer thread will get all messages for that value of JMSXGroupID / NMSXGroupID

Comment: I think I get it. In my own words: Each message group id will get hashed to a finite list of possible codes. Tcodes are then assigned to consumers

Comment: I think I get it. In my own words: Each message group id will get hashed to a finite list of possible codes, and these codes are what are assigned to consumers.  Is this correct?

Comment: As I read in the [doc link](http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html), this is not default behaviour and `messageGroupHashBucked` needs to be configured for the queue. Is there a way to configure `messageGroupHashBucked` from Java client, possibly when creating queue or by any other means? Needing to configure it in broker server adds an operational step.

Comment: For searchers coming here from google I can confirm that messageGroupHashBucked was/is no longer the default way for handling message groups. It originally was but was quietly changed at one point. Not knowing this caused our team huge headaches since our message groups were expiring and we didn't know why.